# Sum Non Adjacent Columns based on Criteria Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, multiple-columns

I need to be able to sum the values in non-adjacent columns (i.e. D and E), using a criteria based on another column.[image]

I Found recently in excel forum a response to the question on : "How sum Multiple columns based on a criteria...".

Based on the Formula `=SUMPRODUCT((A4:A9="Football")\*(B4:D9))` the result for "Football" is 24.

What I need to Know is, if there are a way of calculating a sum only for the columns [B] and [D] - (B4:B9) + (D4:D9), avoiding to use the fomula below:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A4:A9="Football")\*(B4:B9))+SUMPRODUCT((A4:A9="Football")\*(D4:D9))
```

In this case thw result for "Football" would be:
(4+2)+(1+2)+(1+3) = 13.

many thank's in advance,

Leopoldo Fernandes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the fashion you are trying it with a `SUMPRODUCT` it would look like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A4:A9="Football")*(B4:B9+D4:D9))
```

And another fashion, to exclude a certain column from the range `B4:D9` could be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A4:A9="Football")*(COLUMN(B4:D9)<>3),B4:D9)
```

But another (possible better way) would be to use multiple `SUMIF`:

```
=SUMIF(A4:A9,"Football",B4:B9)+SUMIF(A4:A9,"Football",D4:D9)
```

---

EDIT:

To explain the second formula; it does first check column A against your lookup value returning an array of `TRUE` and `FALSE` values. We then check our range of values `B4:D9` (might as well make that `B4:D4`) and only return `TRUE` in the matrix if it is not column number 3. Now we made our matrix, the second parameter can be the full range so `SUMPRODUCT` knows whichs values to pick up and add.

[image]

As you can see, the formula returns 13 to me, not 15.

Comment: Thank you very mutch. Can you please explain the 2º Formula. I'm getting as result 15 and not 13.

Comment: All the best for you. You've been a great help.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A7="Football")*B2:D7*ISNUMBER(FIND(B1:D1,"Week1|Week3")))
```

The formula would need to be adjusted if one column header could be a substring of another:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A7="Football")*B2:D7*ISNUMBER(FIND("|"&B1:D1&"|","|Week1|Week3|")))
```

This is potentially a bit more general because you could specify several column headers.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Solution]

My approach is essentially the same as the 2nd approach provided by JvdV.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A4:A9="Football")*(B3:D3<>"Week 2")*B4:D9)
```

Cheers :)

Comment: Thank you very much Terry W. Wish you all the best.